# Обрезать строку по известному количеству символов в конце

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

есть строка:

```
mystr = 'sometext888999'
```

мне нужно получить число на конце 888999
проблема в том, что sometext постоянно разный и разной длины, и replace я использовать не могу
а код вида:

```
mystr2 = str(mystr)[:-6]
```

оставляет часть перед нужными цифрами, которую мне наоборот, надо откинуть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо всего лишь `-6` ставить не после двоеточия, а перед ним:

```
mystr2 = mystr[-6:]
```

Ну и явно приводить к строке `str(mystr)` не нужно, у вас же и так `mystr` - строка.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать инвертировать строку, отрезать первые 6 символов, а потом их уже инвертировать снова

Например:

```
a = "abc123456"
b = "ab789090"
c = "sometext654321"
ar = a[::-1]
br = b[::-1]
cr = c[::-1]
print(ar[:6][::-1])
print(br[:6][::-1])
print(cr[:6][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

number = re.findall(r'\d+$', mystr)[0]
print(number)  # 888999
```